# implementing namespace function javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm implementing Stoyan Stefanov's javascript namespace function as I have been reading his very informative JavaScript Patterns book; in my web application but not sure if I'm using it the proper way

here is the funciton implementation i'm using on my web app on this page http://dalydd.com/projects/module_example/

```
     var COOP = COOP || {};

    COOP.namespace = function (ns_string) {
    var parts = ns_string.split('.'),
    parent = COOP,
    i;
     // strip redundant leading global
    if (parts[0] === "COOP") {
        parts = parts.slice(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 1) {
    // create a property if it doesn't exist
        if (typeof parent[parts[i]] === "undefined") {
            parent[parts[i]] = {};
        }

        parent = parent[parts[i]];
    }
    return parent;
};


     COOP.namespace('sliderContainer')
     COOP.sliderContainer = function () {
     return slider = ($('#slider').length > 0) ? $('#slider') : $('#element_temp'); 
}   // we need this at the beginning as others are dependent on it and call it initially
```

my goal is to check every new property of COOP to see if it exists before it's implemented --- so if I create a property of COOP called COOP.sliderContainer - I want to make sure COOP.sliderContainer does not exist already.  when I use the namespace function it returns an object but COOP.sliderContainer is a function.  I feel like I have to do an extra layer of abstraction in order to name this namespace function work properly like

```
 var sliderContainer = COOP.namespace('sliderContainer');
 sliderContainer.sliderContainer = function () {
 return slider = ($('#slider').length > 0) ? $('#slider') : $('#element_temp'); 
 }
```

this seems silly and redundant to me - is there a better way to do this?

any info is appreciated as always - the page has a direct link to the js file on it

Comment: My main goal in creating this application is to produce modular javascript - it's just an example of how I think code should be organized

Comment: There isn't an "extra layer of abstraction", you're simply assigning a function to a property of the namespace which you created. If you want to assign the function to `COOP.sliderContainer`, then assign the function directly to it instead of creating another object (namespace) with that name.

Comment: thanks Fabricio - how do I check and make sure COOP.sliderContainer doesn't already exist other than doing something like this  
if (typeof COOP.sliderContainer === "undefined") {
     COOP.sliderContainer = function() {
     }
}
each time - maybe i'm not grasping it correctly just a little frustrated I guess

Comment: um... is it just `"undefined" == typeof COOP['{some namespace}']` ? I think if you really want to go deep in modular javascript, take a look on commonJS / requireJS.

Comment: @JamesDaly You mean inside of your function? Ah, either way you will need that check. I guess `if (typeof parent[parts[i]] !== 'undefined') parent[parts[i]] = {};`

Comment: thanks Cauliturtle - I have looked at some some various javascript MVC's which are good I believe but if you are a small group of developers I'm just trying to create a common pattern without having to use a new library to organize code - I usually use simple objects and make everything public but I live the modular version very you make public and private methods returning an object with public methods

Comment: I may be a little sleepy, but I guess my last piece of code should take care of `COOP.namespace` to don't overwrite existing namespaces. If you need to protect the generated namespaces' properties from being overwritten, then you will need another abstraction level.

Comment: I think that's what I need Fabricio is another abstraction layer because the code above creates an object if undefined I would like to create whatever a user chooses I guess it could be a funciton, string, number or any other data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

namespace function is useful when create sub namespaces inside COOP, it will help to avoid multiple checkings. For example you want to create **COOP.module.module1**, you have to make 2 checks to see if module and module 1 are not defined or not.

However, in this case, sliderContainer is just a property of COOP. There's no need to use namespace. You just simply check it yourself:

```
if(COOP.sliderContainer === undefined){
    // define it
}
```

**EDIT**

You can have a function handle that for you:

```
COOP.createProperty = function(name, prop){
    if(COOP[name] === undefined){
        COOP[name] = prop;
    }
}
```

then

```
COOP.createProperty("sliderContainer", function(){  
    // do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: I was thinking that to namkha87 but everytime I crate a property I don't want to it to be wrapped inside an if statement that seems like messy code no? so I want to create a function or modify the namespace function to do exactly what you are doing with the if statement just check it if its undefined and then implement it

Comment: I update the answer, you can write a function similar to namespace to handle this check

Comment: Ah, brilliant - that helped me a lot - that looks similar to the method method that Crockford uses - thanks a bunch